# i want to register user in laravel 5.2 by ajax, but the image file always turn null, why?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, image-uploading

my ajax code is:

```
$('form.employeeForm').on('submit',function(){
  $("span").hide();
 $(".danger").removeClass("danger");
 var that=$(this),
    url=that.attr('action'),
    method=that.attr('method'),
    data={};
that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value){
    var that=$(this),
        name=that.attr('name'),
        value=that.val();
    data[name]=value;


});
 console.log(data);
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': data['_token']
    }
 });

 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#addEmployee').val('Recording data..........');
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#addEmployee').val('Save Record');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },

       error: function(data){
            var errors= data.responseJSON;
            //var error=errors.name[0];
           $.each(errors.errors, function(key, value) {
                  console.log(key,value);
                  //$('input','textarea').removeClass('error');
                  var           dtextarea=$('textarea[name="'+key+'"]').closest('textarea[name="'+key+'"]');
                  dtextarea.next('.text-danger').remove();
                  dtextarea.addClass('danger').after("<span class='text-danger'>"+value+"<br></span>");
                  var dinput=$('input[name="'+key+'"]').closest('input[name="'+key+'"]');
                  dinput.next('.text-danger').remove();
                  dinput.addClass('danger').after("<span class='text-danger'>"+value+"<br></span>");
                  //$('input[name="'+key+'"]').addClass('danger').closest('input[name="'+key+'"]').after("<span class='text-danger'>"+value+"</span>");
            });

               }
        });  

return false;
});
```

Controller Code is:

```
public function eregister(Request $request){
    if ($request->ajax()) {
          $rules = [

              'full_name' => 'required',
              'image' => 'required',
              'eid' => 'required',
              'username' => 'required',
              'address' => 'required',
              'join_date' => 'required',
              'n_id_no' => 'required',
              'position' => 'required',
              'blood' => 'required',
              'birth_date' => 'required',
              // 'role' => 'required',
              'phone_no' => 'required',
              'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
              'password' => 'required|confirmed',
              'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6',
          ];
          $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
         $errors=$validation->errors();
   //print_r($errors->image);
          if ($validation->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                                        'status' => 'false',
                                        'errors'  =>$validation->errors()],    400);
            //return response()->json($validation->errors());
          } else {
              $uploadDirectory = 'uploads/';
              $file = $request->file('image');
              $filename = $request->input('username') . "." . $file-  >getClientOriginalName();
              $saveData = new User();
              if ($file->move($uploadDirectory, $filename)) {
                  $saveData->image = $filename;
                  $saveData->position = $request->input('position');
                  $saveData->full_name = $request->input('full_name');
                  $saveData->eid = $request->input('eid');
                  $saveData->phone_no = $request->input('phone_no');
                  $saveData->username = $request->input('username');
                  $saveData->address = $request->input('address');
                  $saveData->join_date = $request->input('join_date');
                  $saveData->n_id_no = $request->input('n_id_no');

                  $saveData->email = $request->input('email');
                  $saveData->blood = $request->input('blood');
                  $saveData->birth_date = $request->input('birth_date');
                  $saveData->status =1;
                  $saveData->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
                  if($saveData->save()){
                return response()->json([
                                        'status' => 'true',
                                        'errors'  =>null], 200);
            }
              }
          }
      } else {
          return view('auth.register');
      }
}
```

The problem is it always fires the error block of ajax though the form validation succeeded. I have debug the response of ajax for a validate form it returns 500 on network tab and the reason is the $file variable got null though i select an image file.

Comment: Check your form's enctype='multipart/form-data'

Comment: yes it is enctype='multipart/form-data'. though i am getting problem

Comment: try with // Serialize the form data.......
    var formData = $form.serialize(); and pass it to data in ajax

Comment: it turns error and function stops working